# Identify Methods Assigned to DoWork

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I inherited an application that uses a Background Worker. Through the course of the application, there are multiple functions assigned to and removed from DoWork (see below). Is there a property or a method that can be called to evaluate which methods are currently assigned to the DoWork function, or is this something that should be tracked by the application?

ex:

```
worker.DoWork += method1;

{ Run some code }

worker.DoWork -= method1;

worker.DoWork += method2;

{ Run some code }

worker.DoWork -= method2;
```

Comment: It is very wonky code, impossible to guess why its author liked to do it this way.  Throwing it away is the best you could do with it.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a [custom event accessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-custom-event-accessors). Of course since it's custom, you end up doing the tracking yourself, but here's how you can do it.

```
class MyClass
{
    protected readonly List<EventHandler> list = new List<EventHandler>();

    public event EventHandler DoWork
    {
        add
        {
            list.Add(value);
        }
        remove
        {
            list.Remove(value);
        }
    }

    public void RaiseDoWork()
    {
        var args = new EventArgs();
        foreach (var func in list)
        {
            func(this, args);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<EventHandler> GetDoWorkDelegates()
    {
        return list;
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void HandleDoWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event fired.");
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var c = new MyClass();
        c.DoWork += HandleDoWork; 
        c.RaiseDoWork();

        foreach (var d in c.GetDoWorkDelegates())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method name was {0}.", d.Method.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Event fired.
Method name was HandleDoWork.
```

[Working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R33upr)

Note: More code is needed if you want the above to be thread-safe.

Answer (score -2):

The entire purpose of using events, rather than just delegates, is that it specifically *prevents* any code external to the type from doing anything other than adding or removing a handler.  You can neither invoke, nor inspect, all of the handlers added to the event.